# JPQL Group By With Multiple Fields

Tags: java, sql, jpa, playframework, jpql

I would like help understanding the following JPQL query.  The context is a simple blog application, where posts and tags have a many to many relationship.  We are trying to find posts tagged with all of the tags being passed to the method:

```java
public static List<Post> findTaggedWith(String... tags) {
    return Post.find(
            "select distinct p from Post p join p.tags as t where t.name in (:tags) group by p.id, p.author, p.title, p.content,p.postedAt having count(t.id) = :size"
    ).bind("tags", tags).bind("size", tags.length).fetch();
}
```

Basically, I would just like someone to break down for me what is going on in that query.  Specifically, I am confused by using GROUP BY with multiple fields.  I would think that if we are grouping by id, which is unique, that grouping by anything else would be superfluous.  What am I missing?